# lose bytes Socket Programming

Tags: c#, sockets

i am developing application which send and receive data between two computers but there is problem which i am facing when i send data the file size would be 4.56 kb but when i receive data on other side the file size reduce to 1.42 kb and data write in file also in complete my receiving byte size is 1024 * 5000.i am using c#.i am using TCP

here is my code

i am first sending data to tell other computer what file i want to receive

```
 private void GetLoginFile()
    {
        Socket clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            char[] delimiter = splitter.ToCharArray();
            byte[] fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myIP + "_GetLoginFile"); //file name
            byte[] fileData;
            fileData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("null");
            //byte[] fileData = reads.ReadToEnd().to; //file
            byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileName.Length); //lenght of file name
            clientData = new byte[4 + fileName.Length + fileData.Length];

            fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
            fileName.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
            fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileName.Length);
            System.Net.IPAddress ipAdd = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(serverIP);

            IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ipAdd, 9050);
            clientSock.Connect(ipEnd); //target machine's ip address and the port number
            clientSock.Send(clientData);

            byte[] clientData1 = new byte[1024 * 5000];
            string receivedPath = mypath + "XML\\";

            int receivedBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData1);

            int fileNameLen1 = BitConverter.ToInt32(clientData1, 0);

            string fileName1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientData1, 4, fileNameLen1);
            //string file = Encoding.UTF8.GetString();

            BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath + fileName1, FileMode.Append));
            bWrite.Write(clientData1, 4 + fileNameLen1, receivedBytesLen - 4 - fileNameLen1);
            //clientSock.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);

            bWrite.Close();
            clientSock.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            clientSock.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

can anyone help me out to solve this problem.

Comment: Please provide some code and some more detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you haven't given any code... but I *suspect* it's your receiving code which is wrong.

You should be looping round, reading until a `Read` call on the stream returns 0. Don't assume you'll get all the data in one call.

EDIT: Yup, look at your receiving code:

```
int receivedBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData1);
```

What makes you think you've received all the data you need in that one call? You need to loop round, receiving until either the other end closes the connection, or you've read all the data you need.

Comment: Check your encoding too, it can halve the size

Comment: This is a best bet without any code, though is there a reason you don't suggest a NetworkStream where you can ReadByte() untill !NetworkStream.DataAvailable?

Comment: @Jimmy: **Don't** use Stream.DataAvailable - that doesn't tell you anything useful, other than calling Read will block. In particular, it doesn't mean that you've received all the data sent by the other side - more can be in transit.

Comment: guys i didn't get any solution please help me out.

Comment: @Jon: how i can make it loop round?can you give me any code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using UDP sockets? If so, then everything is fine: udp is not reliable. Use TCP to get every single byte sent.